# PHP substr returning full text

Tags: php, wordpress, substring, rss

I'm trying to put a max on the length of my title in an RSS feed. I'm using substr but whatever I try, it won't actually shorten the text. I'm guessing the problem has to do with importing text from another php function. I also tried the mb_substr, but with the same results.

I'm currently using this code:

```
function customtitle() {
$titleimport = the_title_rss();
$titlelength = strlen($titleimport);
if ($titlelength > 5) {
echo mb_substr($titleimport, 0 , 5, 'utf-8')."...";
} 
else {
echo $titleimport;
}
}
```

Which in the rss item `<title><?php customtitle(); ?></title>` just gives me the full title, exactly what `the_title_rss()` would return.

The basic version, something like below, also won't work.

```
function customtitle() {
$titleimport = the_title_rss();
$shorttitle = substr($titleimport,0,5);
echo $shorttitle;
}
```

Any ideas how to actually cut off this thing?

Comment: Try echoing the length and see what the actual length is

Comment: Echoing the length returns the full title plus a '0' at the end, using:  $titleimport = the_title_rss(); $titlelength = strlen($titleimport); echo $titlelength;'

Comment: [the_totle_rss](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title_rss/) immediately echos the title, it doesn't return anything.  You probably want [get_the_title_rss()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title_rss/)

Comment: get_the_title worked like a charm, thank you so much!